# is there a way have eclipse automatically remove the warning that I've already fixed?

Tags: eclipse

eclipse tells there is a warning

[image]

which I've already fixed.

[image]

is there a way have eclipse automatically remove the warning?

Comment: Make sure in _Project > Properties: Java Compiler_ the checkbox _Use compliance from execution environment..._ is checked. For Java 13 Eclipse 2019-09 with the [_Java 13 Support for Eclipse 2019-09 (4.13)_](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-13-support-eclipse-2019-09-413) plug-in is required.

Comment: Warnings are normally removed automatically. If you don't have the Java 13 support patch installed Eclipse doesn't understand the Java 13 JRE/JDK properly and won't be able to clear the warning. Or wait for Eclipse 2019-12 which will be released in a few days.